# If $a_1a_2a_3...a_{20}=1$ find minimum value of S

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

Given that

If $$a_1a_2a_3...a_{20}=1$$
then what is the minimum value of 
$$\frac{a_1}{1+a_1}+\frac{a_2}{(1+a_1)(1+a_2)}+...+\frac{a_{20}}{(1+a_1)(1+a_2)...(1+a_{20})}=S$$

Please Suggest me how to start?

Comment: I would start by solving the analogous problem with $2$ or $3$ variables to get an idea what the answer might be.

Comment: Hint: $S = 1 - \prod_{k=1}^{20}\frac{1}{1+a_k}$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Define a more general sum:

$$S_n=\frac{a_1}{1+a_1}+\frac{a_2}{(1+a_1)(1+a_2)}+...+\frac{a_{n}}{(1+a_1)(1+a_2)...(1+a_{n})}$$

In your particular case $n=20$. Let us first show that:

$$S_n=1-\frac{1}{\prod_{i=1}^n(1+a_i)}\tag{1}$$

You can guess that formula by adding a few starting items and you can rigorously prove it by induction. It is obviously true for $n=1$:

$$S_1=1-\frac{1}{1+a_1}=\frac{a_1}{1+a_1}$$

On the other side:

$$S_{n+1}=S_n+\frac{a_{n+1}}{(1+a_1)(1+a_2)...(1+a_{n})(1+a_{n+1})}$$

$$S_{n+1}=1-\frac{1}{\prod_{i=1}^n(1+a_i)}+\frac{a_{n+1}}{\prod_{i=1}^{n+1}(1+a_i)}$$

$$S_{n+1}=1-\frac{1+a_{n+1}}{\prod_{i=1}^{n+1}(1+a_i)}+\frac{a_{n+1}}{\prod_{i=1}^{n+1}(1+a_i)}$$

$$S_{n+1}=1-\frac{1}{\prod_{i=1}^{n+1}(1+a_i)}$$

So (1) is definitely correct.

To minimize $S_n$ you have to minimize the product:

$$P_n=\prod_{i=1}^{n}(1+a_i)$$

By simple AM-GM inequality we know that:

$$1+a_i\ge2\sqrt{a_i}$$

Equality is reached only for $a_i=1$. It follows that:

$$P_n=\prod_{i=1}^{n}(1+a_i)\ge2^n\sqrt{\prod_{i=1}^{n}a_i}$$

Assuming that $\prod_{i=1}^{n}a_i=1$:

$$P_n\ge2^n$$

$$S_n\ge1-\frac{1}{P_n}$$

$$S_n\ge1-\frac{1}{2^n}$$

Minimum value:

$$(S_n)_{min}=1-\frac{1}{2^n}$$

...is reached for $a_1=a_2=\dots=a_n=1$

Comment: Great answer [+1]! However, I have a question: You've used the AM-GM inequality in order to prove that $$1+a_i\ge 2\sqrt{a_i}$$ However, in order to use this inequality, you assume that $a_i\ge 0$. What happens if this is not the case?

Comment: I'm not sure that this problem makes sense for the mix of positive and negative values. Most inequality problems are restricted to non-negative values only.